# How to get complete row when using max(points) AS in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using this code.

```
$query = "SELECT max(Points) AS Points,City FROM Table_name WHERE Gender='Female' && Country='England' GROUP BY City";
```

I want it to give the complete row, not just Points and City. 
In my database the order is ID, City, Points, Name, Gender, Country.
When I run this line of code it only gives me Points and City.

> I have tried * but doesn't work.

Comment: What does && mean in MySQL? (Maybe a stupid question, but I'm not a MySQL user....)

Comment: `AND` is Standard SQL

`&&` is proprietary syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want the whole row with the max points value, i.e. rows with Female/England/city where there are no one with higher points:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_name t1
WHERE Gender='Female' 
 AND Country='England'
 AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Table_name t2
                 WHERE t2.Gender='Female' 
                   AND t2.Country='England'
                   AND t2.city = t1.city
                   AND t2.points > t1.points)
```

Will show both rows if it's a tie.

To return only one row / city, just add an < id condition in the `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_name t1
WHERE Gender='Female' 
 AND Country='England'
 AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Table_name t2
                 WHERE t2.Gender='Female' 
                   AND t2.Country='England'
                   AND t2.city = t1.city
                   AND t2.points > t1.points
                   AND t2.id < t1.id)
```

Comment: thanks but how do I change that so it doesn't show same city twice? (if 2 different names in same city has same points).

Comment: Which one do you want?

Comment: The one with lowest ID number. :)

Comment: @AlexanderVestling, will probably work with MySQL at least... Can you please check if my later query works or not? (Now when I've spent time working on it...)

Comment: I ran your < id in EXISTS, code. But that outputs same city more than once.

Comment: But thanks for the first part anyway:) thats what I'm using now, with GROUP BY in the end ofcourse. Marked as answered!